# Hiding Tablix in SSRS report using Expressions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report in which there are two tables from the ***same dataset***, and i want to hide second table when the report runs at first, then ***when i click on the Product id*** i want to display the second table
Anyone help?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Ed3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this by clicking on a textbox within a table as it might be out of scope, but if your first tablix is just a single line then you could just use a series of textboxes to emulate the 1st tablix.

Once you have done this, set the ToggleItem property of the 2nd tablix to be the name of the textbox that contains the ProductID.

I've just tested this and it works as expected.

...and if that does not help...
If your 1st tablix shows mutliple rows, you might want to consider adding a second row to it with the columns you require from your 2nd tablix and setting the toggleitem property of the 2nd row.

Comment: Thanks Alan Schofield